# Response time increased after using Google Cloud Sql proxy

Tags: hibernate, kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, dropwizard, google-kubernetes-engine

After deploying our application on Google Container engine and connecting to Google Cloud Sql through Cloud Sql proxy as per official documentation  ,api's response time has been increased by at-least 100 ms as compare to connecting to  Cloud Sql via ip whitelisting from Google Compute Engine instance .

I have wrote a simple api which was starting a transaction  on mysql and committing it using hibernate . Below are the results

```
+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| App Deployed on | Number of Requests | 99th percentile | Connecting Via  |
+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| GKE             |              20140 |           113ms | Cloud Sql Proxy |
| GCE             |              20895 |            13ms | IP whitelisting |
+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

My app is based on Dropwizard framework and I am using dropwizard-hibernate,below is  connection  configuration , which is same for both GCE and GKE :

```
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: db_user
  password: db_user_pass

  url: jdbc:mysql://HOST_IP/db_name?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s      
  validationQuery: "SELECT 1"    
  minSize: 8    
  maxSize: 42
  properties:
      charSet: UTF-8         
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate         
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
  maxConnectionAge : 10s
  checkConnectionOnBorrow: true
```

Api code on which above experiment has been run .

```
    @GET
    @Path("/response/test")
    @UnitOfWork
    public LeaderBoardResp getLeaderBoardTest(){
        long timeSpent = System.currentTimeMillis() - RequestThreadContext.get().getStartTimeMillis();
        log.info(" Got a request on test api");
        Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        try {
            LeaderBoardResp leaderBoardResp = new LeaderBoardResp();
//                    fetchLeaderBoard.fetchLeaderBoard(leaderBoardReq);
            return leaderBoardResp;
        }finally {
            stopWatch.stop();
            log.info("total time in ms :: {} reqfilter time :: {} ",stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),timeSpent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're already discussing this at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/87

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan yeah but still unresolved .